# The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the Java Build Path error persists

Tags: eclipse

I know this is a duplicate question, but all the answers in the question dont work.

I have added the server to the build path, added the jar to web-inf and all other.

Im using the Spring IDE and and upgraded. The

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
```

Still gets the not found in build path. And Ive worked on this one issue for two days now. I tried to use maven to build but maven wont run. It gives me a "invalid department description" error. What ever that is.

Is this a bug in eclipse? Can someone, anyone please help me?

Comment: Are you sure that's the error message you were given? Are you actually using Maven for building or aren't you? What happens when you Clean and rebuild the project?

Comment: *I have added the server to the build path* What does that mean. Post screenshots of the build path window.